# I can't purge all chains

Tags: parachain, validator, relay-chain, collator

I wanted to purge all chains, a relay chain with 3 validators and 2 parachains with 1 collator per each, so I removed all of their DB folders by using `rm -rf` command.
E.g ;

```
rm -rf /tmp/parachain
rm -rf /tmp/relay
rm -rf /tmp/relay-bob
rm -rf /tmp/relay-charlie
```

But when I re-ran the validators, I could see the chain state was not initialized yet.
Why did it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you purge the DB?

Did you stop all nodes before the purge?

I guess you:

1. stop relay
2. purge relay
3. restart relay (it will sync the data from the running chain)
4. stop relay-bob
5. purge relay-bob
6. restart relay-bob (it will sync the data from the running chain)

Comment: Thanks. it worked.

Comment: So, please mark this as the answer.